# Understanding symmetry arguments to derive the coupling coefficients between modes of a unit cell in a periodic system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, symmetry

I am reading a paper that derives the form of the Bloch Hamiltonian using the symmetry arguments. Let $D(k)$ be the Bloch Hamiltonian, where $k$ is the wavenumber. The part that I am trying to understand is

[image]

What I understand is that the authors are describing the Bloch Hamiltonian in terms of the eigenmodes of a unit cell at $k=0$. One of the eigenmodes is symmetric under reflection, and the other is antisymmetric under reflection. When $k \neq 0$, the modes couple with each other, and we want to find the coupling coefficients.

Since the two eigenmodes have different frequencies, it gives rise to the coefficients of the identity matrix and the 3rd Pauli matrix. The part that I don't understand is highlighted in yellow. Why is it that a symmetric eigenmode couples to the neighboring unit cell's antisymmetric eigenmode with a coefficient $-u$, but the antisymmetric eigenmode couples to the neighboring unit cell's symmetric eigenmode with a coefficient $u$? Why are they equal and opposite?

Paper reference: Supplementary material of Süsstrunk, R., & Huber, S. D. (2016). Classification of topological phonons in linear mechanical metamaterials. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 113(33), E4767-E4775.